# Flutter/Android: How to manipulate audio file in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, audio

I have some audio files that I want to manipulate (ex: change pitch, add echo, add delay...). How can I do that in flutter?

Comment: @gtxtreme please post this as an answer as it solved my problem, and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg is the most powerful encoding/decoding and manipulation tool for videos and audios

You can use [Flutter FFMpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) when using flutter and you want to leverage the power of ffmepg

Note : Posted as answer on request of OP